# Parameter must be an array or an object metaboxes-framework/init.php

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Need help please!

**metaboxes-framework/init.php**

```
// if it's an array of one, extract it
elseif  ( is_array( $meta_box['pages'] ) && count( $meta_box['pages'] === 1 ) )
$type = is_string( end( $meta_box['pages'] ) ) ? end( $meta_box['pages'] ) : false;
```

> Parameter must be an array or an object metaboxes-framework/init.php

How can I correct this so that I don't get this error?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way:

```
// if it's an array of one, extract it
elseif  ( is_array( $meta_box['pages'] ) && count( $meta_box['pages']) === 1  )
$type = is_string( end( $meta_box['pages'] ) ) ? end( $meta_box['pages'] ) : false;
```

The closing parenthesis needs to be after the closing bracket, the way it's written originally means that it tries to count a boolean because the argument passed to count is $meta_box['pages] === 1

Funny thing is that I had exactly the same error in a WP plugin I installed and I didn't see it in my code editor so came across this question and immediately spotted the mistake :D